# map the kinect joint position to 2d point

Tags: xna, kinect

I am new to  programming using official Kinect SDK 1.5 in XNA. How do I map the Skeleton joint's position to the XNA 2D screen to match the image stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy since the Kinect SDK provides some Mapping helper methods.

MapSkeletonPointToColor will gives you the position of a SkeletonPoint in a 2D color frame. You just jave to pass two arguments : your skeleton point, and the target color frame format.

```
foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
{
    // Transforms a SkeletonPoint to a ColorImagePoint
    var colorPoint = Kinect.MapSkeletonPointToColor(joint.Position, Kinect.ColorStream.Format);

    // colorPoint has two properties : X and Y which gives you the positions in the 2D color frame.
    // TODO : Do something with the colorPoint value. 
}
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, don't hesitate to mark this response as the answer ;)

Comment: But, how to do it when Image element that renders the skeleton dont have the default 640x480 size?

Comment: With the MapSkeletonPointToColor method, you can pass the output format you want (one that is proposed by the SDK). If you then use a different format, you have to do some math.

Comment: @Renaud Dumont I know this, i am asking for "The Math"

Comment: @Ewerton maybe I don't get what you really want, but it looks like a simple rule of three. From 640x480 to 480x360, it's a 4/3 scale.

So you take the coordinates, and you multiply by 4/3, and you're done !

Comment: @Renaud Dumont you,re right. I solved my problem and will answer it on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495402/how-to-do-joint-tracking-in-kinect-with-a-scaled-image.