# How to do Joint tracking in Kinect with a scaled Image

Tags: scale, kinect, kinect-sdk

I trying to do some Joint Tracking with kinect (just put a ellipse inside my right hand) everything works fine for a default 640x480 Image, i based myself in [this](http://ak.channel9.msdn.com/ch9/e017/c2943395-cca6-4601-a493-9fea003de017/SkeletalTrackingFundamentals_high_ch9.mp4) channel9 video.
My code, updated to use the new CoordinateMapper classe is here

```
 ...
CoordinateMapper cm = new CoordinateMapper(this.KinectSensorManager.KinectSensor);
ColorImagePoint handColorPoint = cm.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(atualSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

Canvas.SetLeft(elipseHead, (handColorPoint.X) - (elipseHead.Width / 2)); // center of the ellipse in center of the joint
Canvas.SetTop(elipseHead, (handColorPoint.Y) - (elipseHead.Height / 2));
```

This works. The question is:

**How to do joint tracking in a scaled image, 540x380 for example?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this is pretty simple, i fugured it out.

What a need to do is find some factor to apply to the position.
This factor can be found takin the atual ColorImageFormat of the Kinect and dividing by the desired size, example:

Lets say i am working with the `RgbResolution640x480Fps30` format and my Image (ColorViewer) have 220x240. So, lets find the factor for X:

```
double factorX = (640 / 220); // the factor is 2.90909090...
```

And the factor for y:

```
double factorY = (480/ 240); // the factor is 2...
```

Now, i adjust the position of the ellipse using this factor.

```
Canvas.SetLeft(elipseHead, (handColorPoint.X / (2.909090)) - (elipseHead.Width / 2));
Canvas.SetTop(elipseHead, (handColorPoint.Y / (2)) - (elipseHead.Height / 2));
```

Comment: Note that (elipseHead.Width / 2) and (elipseHead.Height / 2) is just to put the center os the ellipse in the center of the joint

Answer (score 2):

I've not used the `CoordinateMapper` yet, and am not in front on my Kinect at the moment, so I'll toss out this first.  I'll see about an update when I get working with the Kinect again.

The [Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit](http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/) has a `ScaleTo` extension as part of the library.  This adds the ability to take a joint and scale it to any display resolution.

The scaling function looks like this:

```
private static float Scale(int maxPixel, float maxSkeleton, float position)
{
    float value = ((((maxPixel / maxSkeleton) / 2) * position) + (maxPixel/2));
    if(value > maxPixel)
        return maxPixel;
    if(value < 0)
        return 0;
    return value;
}
```

`maxPixel` = the width or height, depending on which coordinate your scaling.
`maxSkeleton` = set this to 1.
`position` = the `X` or `Y` coordinate of the joint you want to scale.

If you were to just include the above function you could call it like so:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(e, Scale(640, 1, joint.Position.X));
Canvas.SetTop(e, Scale(480, 1, -joint.Position.Y));
```

... replacing your 640 & 480 with a different scale.

If you include the [Coding4Fun Kinect Toolkit](http://c4fkinect.codeplex.com/), instead of re-writing code, you could just call it like so:

```
scaledJoin = rawJoint.ScaleTo(640, 480);
```

... then plug in what you need.

Comment: Almost worked @Evil Closet Monkey The ellipse gets a little displaced. I find a way to solve my problem and will answer my own question. Any way, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see where I steered you wrong.  Skeleton points are generated from the depth data, so these points should sync up with the depth image (I'll have to test that for 100% certainty).  But the slight shift you saw was due to the slightly different field of views between the two cameras.

Comment: seems true, since the coding for fun Skeleton Basics video uses depht data to map to skeleton then to a color. I Solved my problem (see my answer below, whats do you think about my solution?)

Comment: Your answer seems to be very simple and the right course to take.  Be sure to accept your own answer to highlight the better path over mine. :)